# Closing web enabled infopath 2010 form code behind sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, infopath-data-connections

We have a custom button, which when clicked sets few fields in infopath form and then does data submit using data connection, now we want to close the form after data submit. Any suggestions?

this is how data is being submitted

```
        DataConnection submitConn = DataConnections["SharePoint Library Submit"];

        submitConn.Execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

**A web-based form can only be closed with a rule**

You can only close an InfoPath form (web-based) if you create a rule with an action that says:

> Close the form
>
> In addition, such a rule can only be set on a button control, which
>   means that you will not be able to close an InfoPath form when a user
>   changes the value of a field, but only when a user clicks a button.

**Rules run before code**

A design feature of InfoPath is that rules run before code, which means that even if you write code in a button that has the Close the form action set on it, the code will execute after the Close the form rule runs.

So you won’t be able to close the InfoPath form programmatically by writing code behind a button that has a rule set on it.

**When code runs before rules**

There is an exception to the rules run before code feature, and that is when you use a form’s Submit Options...

On the Submit Options dialog box of an InfoPath form template, you can set a Close the form rule, which will run after the form is submitted. This way you can write code in the FormEvents_Submit event handler to [programmatically submit an InfoPath form](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/browserforms/programmatically-submit-infopath-form-sharepoint-send-email-close-form.htm) and supposedly close the InfoPath form programmatically after submitting it.

**Using a custom Submit button**

By default, the FormEvents_Submit event handler is executed whenever a user clicks the Submit button on the toolbar of a web-based InfoPath form running in InfoPath Forms Services on SharePoint...

But you can also create a button that has a Submit action and hook it up to the FormEvents_Submit event handler.

**Submit to multiple data connections and close the form**

The FormEvents_Submit event handler allows you to write code to execute more than one data connection (e.g., to send data through email in InfoPath, to submit an InfoPath form to a SharePoint library, to submit data from an InfoPath form to a web service, etc.) before closing the InfoPath form.

A good example of this is if you want to programmatically submit an InfoPath form to a SharePoint form library, send an email, and then close the form.

[Source](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/browserforms/programmatically-submit-infopath-form-sharepoint-send-email-close-form.htm)

Comment: great answer! will it be possible to have 2 submit buttons, one who set bunch of field values and submits data to sharepoint  while other just submit data to share point (not setting field values?)

Comment: @spStacker, Ya sure, you can design it on your own way. http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/infopath-help/submit-form-data-to-several-locations-HA010106727.aspx,  https://formotus.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/201042497-How-to-configure-a-multiple-submit,    http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/23136/80220.aspx, These links might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a side note if you use this method to submit and save the form, it will close by default after the procedure in C#:

```
this.Submit();
```